# Device not responding to set address

Tags: android, linux

I just wasted a morning trying to figure this out and I finally did.  There is no hint on SO for this issue, so I thought that I would post my experience and what finally worked.

I am running ubuntu 13.10 and suddenly yesterday when I plugged in my android phone via usb, it fails to mount.  These are errors in /var/log/syslog

```
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.474339] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.474574] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.678542] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.882343] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 9, error -71
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.994413] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  376.994589] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:43 andromeda kernel: [  377.198546] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  377.402455] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 10, error -71
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  377.514497] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  377.514675] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  377.718618] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  377.922524] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 11, error -71
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  378.034578] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  378.034754] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:44 andromeda kernel: [  378.238689] usb 3-3: Device not responding to set address.
Feb  7 12:07:45 andromeda kernel: [  378.442552] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 12, error -71
Feb  7 12:07:45 andromeda kernel: [  378.442592] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
```

I tried all the solutions that I could google and none worked

1. shut down machine & phone, wait a while, then boot and try again
2. reconfigure and or reinstall xserver-xorg and xserver-xorg-core
3. rmmod the usb driver
4. send the device addr to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind

I tried a co-worker's phone in my cable and his phone did the same thing...  Note that this was all working just days ago with the same cable.  So, I finally tried the cable that he was developing with and I got a successful connection and mounted up the phone!  Here is the new output...

```
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.364565] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.384400] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.384442] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.384456] usb 3-3: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.384467] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Feb  7 12:08:27 andromeda kernel: [  421.384473] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 42f72f0c6c809f4b
Feb  7 12:08:28 andromeda colord: Device added: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.553865] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 13
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda colord: device removed: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.824846] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.842489] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.842493] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.842495] usb 3-3: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.842496] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda kernel: [  423.842498] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 42f72f0c6c809f4b
Feb  7 12:08:30 andromeda colord: Device added: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
```

So, if you have tried all the above options and it still fails, perhaps your cable has gone bad...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on unix.SE

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! Very good post. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this along with others as it's technically off-topic, but that doesn't mean it'll be deleted—just "closed" and still visible (and useful) to future viewers. As others have noted, there are separate sites for Android and UNIX that may accept this type of question.

Comment: Micro USB connectors seem in general to have terribly poor reliability.

Comment: This was happening to me on a Linux box with the stock cord for a Samsung G6. Everything seemed to work well on Win8, however. I replaced the cord with an HTC one I had lying around and all was well.